# How to handle errors in PayPal smart button?

Tags: error-handling, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G2sVL.jpg)I want to handle the errors which Paypal returns when payment failed while using Paypal smart button. Here, I am using 'actions.order.authorize' method to make payment authorization. In this scenario, If I get payment failed or any payment errors I have to handle that, So I want to receive the error response as JSON object type. But I am not getting the error in JSON type. I need the error details like debug_id, description, links in JSON type to proceed with the error handling process from our app. Here is the error returns as callback [Click to view image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tYU7t.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

There is some documentation here, though not much about handling errors on the client-side: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/integration-features/auth-capture/#integrate-authorize-capture

You can see if the "authorization" object has those error details, otherwise maybe the `onError` function will be called with them

Comment: Yes, there is not much about handling errors on the client-side. It will return those errors in **onError** function.But the format is not in JSON object. I want to log that details when it returns JSON format.

Comment: It's a parsed JSON object. If you want raw JSON text, you need a server integration.

Comment: I think it's not a parsed JSON object. it's an object only with URLs. there is not much information about payment failure like 'debug_id', 'Error_description', and all. If I want to get all those as a proper JSON object what to do?